# WebMethod returning Json Data with div

Tags: json, ajax, webforms

I have a problem with json parse in webform ajax.

My ajax method:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "VINSearch.aspx/VerifyCaptcha",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {

            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert('Error calling AddBook');
            }
        });
    });
```

My server method:

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static string VerifyCaptcha()
    {
        return "testus";
    }
```

In ajax result I have:

```
"{"d":"\"\\test\""}<div class="timestamp">Processing time: 0,00s</div>"
```

I don't understand why I have div element after json result.

Comment: I don't see how the div is being returned from that method. Are you sure you're not doing something else with the result?

Comment: Also curious where you're viewing that result.